# Android Video not playing in Media Player

Tags: android

I wanted to play a video from  "http://travel.gockell.com//data/251/videos/2016-06-09_13-24-21.mp4" this url.
I am using Media Player to play video,the problem is Media Player doesn't play this url,i tried many other url which work fine except this.
I configured all other thins on manifest like INTERNET Permission.
This video is play on some of device but when using Samsung or LG device it doesn't play.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `adb logcat` for messages from the video decoder.

Not all .mp4 files are alike. MP4 is just the format ("container"). The codec that was used to compress the video might not be supported by this particular device.

For example, it could be H.264 High Profile. Some devices will support it, but the minimum requirements that are supposed to work on all Android devices are pretty low: https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

If you have access to ffmpeg, it includes the ffprobe tool which will print what is the actual codec inside. You can also find general codec info using VLC, in Window > Media Information > Codec Details.

For the specific video you linked:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 79 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2016-06-09 13:23:43
  handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 480x480, 754 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
```

The audio stream is AAC LC, which is not guaranteed to work. The video stream is H.264 Main profile, which is not guaranteed to work either.

Comment: Thanks Brother ,but is there any solution for this,it's only not playing at samsung & Nexus,some other device it's work well.

Comment: You need to transcode the video to one of the formats supported universally on all Android devices.

Comment: The most common supported format is H.264 AVC, and audio codec AAC.